# Excel Macro to copy worksheet to new worksheet paste values only

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a Macro in Excel that will make a copy of the current worksheet and paste the values into a new worksheet.  The worksheet name would be the same just with a number after it  [ie Sheet, Sheet1(2)]

My code does this correctly except that it copies and pastes everything to Sheet1(2).  I only want it to paste the values  (not formulas) from Sheet1 to Sheet1(2).  I'm a novice at vba at best so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
Sub SPACER_Button4_Click()
' Compile Button to Generate Quote
'
'variables definitions
ActiveSheetValue = ActiveSheet.Name
'
'This section creates a copy of the active worksheet and names it with the next corresponding number
    Sheets(ActiveSheetValue).Copy After:=Sheets(ActiveSheetValue)

'This section should look for X value in each row, column 4. If value equals X, it deletes the row on the copied sheet
Dim i As Integer
i = 26
Do Until i > 300
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value = "X" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        Skip = True
    End If
    '
    If Skip = False Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
    '
    Skip = False
Loop

'This part hides columns on Right K thru R of new copied sheet
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("K:R").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just set the values equal to eachother - `Sheets("New Sheet Name").Cells.Value = Sheets("New Sheet Name").Cells.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is contiguous, consider creating a new sheet, selecting and copying the range of data, and pasting onto the new sheet using the below code.

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Dakota: My code copies the Sheet1 to Sheet1(2) which is what I want but I only want to paste values no formulas from Sheet1 to Sheet1(2).  I've tried to select a range and paste values but I add a new worksheet which is name Sheet2 or Sheet3...  I want it to be Sheet1(2), look just like Sheet1 except values only.  I'm not quite sure where or even how to use your syntax above.  I've now ordered 2 books on Excel vba from Amazon just to learn.  So I'm still struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
Sub KopyKat()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim r As Range, addy As String

Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

For Each r In s1.UsedRange
    If r.Value <> "" Then
        If Not r.HasFormula Then
            addy = r.Address
            r.Copy s2.Range(addy)
        End If
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```